# Prove that \frac{2n}{3n+7} converges (Question about my method of proof)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that the sequence $<\frac{2n}{3n+7}>$ converges. Find its limit.

This is the work I have currently:

---

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n}{3n+7} = \frac{2}{3}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$, and observe that:
  \begin{align*}
    \left|\frac{2n}{3n+7} - \frac{2}{3}\right| &= 
    \left|\frac{3(2n) - 2(3n + 7)}{3(3n + 7)}\right|\\
    &= \left|\frac{-14}{9n+21}\right|\\
    &= \frac{14}{9n+21}
  \end{align*}
  We want $\displaystyle \frac{14}{9n+21} < \epsilon$. Solving for $\epsilon$ gives us:
  \begin{align*}
    \displaystyle \frac{14}{9n+21} &< \epsilon\\
    14 &< \epsilon(9n + 21)\\
    \frac{14}{\epsilon} &< 9n + 21\\
    \frac{14}{\epsilon} - 21 &< 9n\\
    \frac{14}{9 \cdot \epsilon} - \frac{7}{3} &< n
  \end{align*}
  So, choose $N$ such that $N = \displaystyle \frac{14}{9 \cdot \epsilon} - \frac{7}{3}$. Then for all $n > N$, we have $\displaystyle \left|\frac{2n}{3n+7} - \frac{2}{3}\right| < \epsilon$.

---

This is the result I came up with for my homework question. I was wondering if when proving convergence the "scratch work" for finding $N$ is included in the proof. (If there is anything else wrong with my proof please let me know)

Comment: Thanks @julien, so $N = \lceil \frac{14}{9 \cdot \epsilon} - \frac{7}{3}} \rceil$ would work for N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just take $$N=\left\lceil\frac{14}{9\epsilon}-\frac73\right\rceil$$ so that $N$ is an integer, then you'll be set. (It actually doesn't matter whether $N$ is an integer, but some texts do specify that $N$ is an integer in their definitions.)

It isn't necessarily required that the "scratch work" be shown in a proof. You can always just pull it out of your hat, and say that if $n>N,$ then $n>\frac{14}{9\epsilon}-\frac73,$ so $9n>\frac{14}\epsilon-21,$ so....

Basically, you'll just be doing the scratchwork in reverse.

Comment: Ah yes, that does seem like a more proper way to do it. Thanks so much.